# C , code runs together

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


char save ();

char save()
{
    char name[30];
    char surname[30];
    char number[12];
    printf("Name    : \n");
    scanf("%d",&name);
    printf("Surname : \n");
    scanf("%d",&surname);
    printf("Number  :\n");
    scanf("%d",&number);
}

int main()
{
    while(1)
    {
        int a;
        printf("please select ");
        scanf("%d",&a);
        switch(a)
    {
        case 1 : save(); break;
        default : printf("ok."); break;
    }
    break;
 }
}
```

when i run save() function with pressing 1, it prints all statements together not one by one.

for example in this code output is:

```
(first output)1- Name  : (i enter my name)
(second output)2- Surname:
                  Number :
```

i would like to run save function's code one by one. how can i fix it?

Comment: Take a look at your format strings on your `scanf` calls.

Comment: c and c++ are distinct languages. This question is about c and should not have had the c++ tag.

Comment: `%d` -> `%s` for string.

Comment: Read up on the [format specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)

Comment: @ChristianGibbons That is soooooooooooooooooooo unimportant.  It has nothing to do with the OP's problem, and you'll only distract or confuse things by bringing it up.

Comment: Because you used the format specifier for `int`  (`%d`) the name you typed was rejected as not being a valid number. The input stays in the buffer until you do something about it, so the same data was rejected by the next two inputs as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change `%d` *(integer)* in your scanf to `%s` *(string)* in your `char save();` function. We use `%d` when we need to read *integer* like `%c` for *char* , `%f` for *float* etc. `%s` is used to read **string** *(char array)* .Your code is not properly intended .Also you do not `return` anything from `char save();` function , whose return type is `char`. If you are not returning any values the you could make return type `void`.

In case of reading strings you don't need `&` operator.Like `scanf("%s", name);`.

Modified code :-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

char save();

char save()
{
    char name[30];
    char surname[30];
    char number[12];
    printf("Name    : \n");
    scanf("%s", name);      //change
    printf("Surname : \n");
    scanf("%s", surname);   //change
    printf("Number  :\n");
    scanf("%s", number);     //change
}

int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        int a;
        printf("please select ");
        scanf("%d", &a);
        switch (a)
        {
        case 1:
            save();
            break;
        default:
            printf("ok.");
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

**Output :-**

```
please select 1
Name    : 
abc
Surname : 
def
Number  :
123
```